# Is section the new div?

Tags: html

I'm trying to do an HTML5 friendly template and as I'm seeing it most of my `<div>` tags are being replaced by `<section>`.

So typically if my original nav is like this this:

```
<nav class="container">
    <div class="row navbar">
        <div class="col-xs-3 relative">
            <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo Voyagemotion"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Accueil</a>
                <li><a href="/bonplans">Bons plans voyage</a>
                <li><a href="/photos">Photos</a>
                <li><a href="/videos">Vidéos</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

it would become:

```
<nav class="container">
    <section class="row navbar">
        <section class="col-xs-3 relative">
            <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo Voyagemotion"/>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-9">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Accueil</a>
                <li><a href="/bonplans">Bons plans voyage</a>
                <li><a href="/photos">Photos</a>
                <li><a href="/videos">Vidéos</a>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Is this a misuse of this tag? Shall I not overuse it?

Comment: `<section>` is for defining unrelated sections of your document. `<div>` is a generic container mostly used for managing flow. Your job as a web developer is to use what makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[A div element](https://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) is a generic container generally used for styling and should be the element of last resort.

> The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its
>   children.

[A section element](https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-section-element) is also generic but is used to group similar and same content together into its own sectioning area.

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.

So, no, a section element is not the new div.

Is your example one of misuse of "section-itis" (the new div-itis)? It looks like it but it also looks generic as if for a framework or template as you say.

The problem with how it is used is it doesn't look like a proper section. There is no grouping of content and there is no heading. Those would be typical of sectioning content but the heading, at least, is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Section is usually used for headers,footers and so on. I would recommend using div. Also, when an element is needed in a certain style, div is recommended.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one would use `<header>` for a header and `<footer>` for a footer.